# Loading object array with a get request

Tags: angular

I am loading a variable with the return of a get request

if I do it that way I have to use another method and I have to use my cbbcategory variable like any

```
  cbbcategory : any;
  loadCombobox() {
    this.categoriaService.getCombobox()
    .subscribe(
      dados=>{ this.exibeLista(dados) },
      (error:any)=>console.log(error)
    );
  }

  loadcbbcategory(dados) {
    this.cbbcategory = dados.result.item;
    console.log(this.cbbcategory );
  }
```

I know that my return json returns me the data in data.item

how can I do a single function that is able to do the request get and load my cbbcategory according to its class?

```
export interface Categoria {
    id: Number;
    descricao: String;
    observacao: String;
    status: String;
}
```

Category.Service

```
getCombobox(){
    return this.http.get(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?getComboBox=true`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
    .pipe(map(response => { return response }))
  }
```

Comment: Actually, you want to do casting of your response?

Comment: I want my get combobox to return me an array of type Category, and that I can retrieve it without the need of the loadcbbcategory

Answer (score 0):

```
  cbbcategory : any;
  loadCombobox() {
    this.categoriaService.getCombobox()
    .subscribe((err,res)=>{
        if(!err)
         {
            Categoria.save(res); 
         }

    });
  }
```

As the response which comes through from any rxjs call is in the form of json by default you directly create your Model.ts file and do a Model.save() directly passing the response to it .

Comment: i want that cbbcategory : Categoria ;

Comment: then you can do something like cbbcategory:Catrgoria=new Categoria();
and do  cbbcategory.save(res)

Answer (score 0):

Make your category service explicit on the JSON:

```
    getCombobox(){
        return this.http.get(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?getComboBox=true`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
        .pipe(map(response => { return response.json() }))
      }
```

And in your combobox

```
  cbbcategory : any;
  categoria: Categoria[];

  loadCombobox() {
    this.categoriaService.getCombobox()
    .subscribe(
      (dados: any[]) =>  this.categoria= dados,
      (error:any) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

Comment: i want that cbbCategory : Categoria

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

service.ts

```
getCombobox(): Observable<Categoria[]>{
        return this.http.get<Categoria[]>(Auth.url + this.nameClass + `?getComboBox=true`, { headers: { 'token': Auth.token } })
        .pipe(map(response => { return response }))
      }
```

component.ts

```
 cbbcategory: Categoria[];

  loadCombobox() {
    this.categoriaService.getCombobox()
      .subscribe(
      (dados: Categoria[]) => this.categoria = dados,
        (error: any) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

Comment: when import {HttpResponse} from '@ angular / common / http';
error '[ts] The type' Observable <Category []> 'can not be assigned to type' Observable <HttpResponse <Category [] >> '.
   Type 'Category []' can not be assigned to type 'HttpResponse <Category []>'.
     The 'body' property is missing in type 'Category []' `

Comment: try updated code and actually `HttpResponse` is used when you want more information about response.